# One word synonym for "easy to follow"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am working on a rubric to grade a presentation, and I am only allowed 4 very short criteria.

After a lot of thinking, the 4 I have chosen are:

1. Organized & Easy to Follow
2. Interesting / Useful
3. Delivery
4. Overall

My question isn't really focused on why I chose these criteria (although suggestions would be appreciated), but more so on the "easy to follow". I am trying to find a shorter, more precise, way to say that the presentation flowed well in a logical and comprehensible manner. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mitch Certainly a possibility, thanks for your input. I think it's just a little too vague.

Comment: Coherence maybe?

Comment: @Jeremy Yup, that's so far my favorite option. Thanks.

Comment: Would the word intuitive suffice?

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for something concise, I would like to suggest the word:

> **[clear](https://www.google.com/search?q=clear%20meaning)**
>   *adjective*
>   1. easy to perceive, understand, or interpret.

Comment: Close, but I still don't feel it captures the element of it being clear *and* in some sort of logical order. Thanks though!

Comment: The presenter's organizational skills lent his talk great CLARITY: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clarity

Comment: Then I think I would use "clear and simple".

Answer (score 4):

#### straightforward

I like it because it implies that somebody following this could repeat it easily and implies direct motion through the steps. Essentially, you have created a path and they just need to go through it. Things like coherence and concise are more value judgement on what you have produced rather than a quality of the path of the final product. I think it also implies that the end user should approach the path with as few ambiguities as possible.

Answer (score 3):

For the first criterion, perhaps **[accessible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessible)**

> easy to appreciate or understand

For the second **[effective](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/effective)**

> attractive or impressive, and producing a definite effect

Answer (score 3):

Your categories lack parallelism: they should be all nouns or all adjectives.  Try:

1. Clarity

   "Clarity" is the right word to cover this criterion, I believe.  A poorly organized presentation will necessarily be unclear.  Poorly explained thoughts would also be unclear.  Insufficient content would also hurt clarity.
2. Relevance & Usefulness

   "Interesting" could refer to either the subject matter or the delivery style. Since Delivery is covered as a separate criterion, you only want to rate the subject matter here.  Therefore, I think "relevance" is a better term.
3. Delivery
4. Miscellaneous

   "Overall" is not a criterion; it is the sum of all factors.  You want a category for "all except the three criteria above", so "miscellaneous" is more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the lack of parallelism. That bugged me right off the bat.

Comment: Very good point, thanks! I realized the awkwardness after I typed, but didn't want to change such a fundamental aspect of the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Collins Online Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/followable):

> **Followable**:
>       adj: able to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use the word **structure** for the whole of point 1?

You could then go for something like:

- structure
- utility
- delivery
- overall

Comment: I actually really like that, thanks! I think I'll have to combine it though, so like "structure and coherence", but I like "structure" more than "organization" in some respects. Utility is good, but I'm not sure everyone would immediately understand what I mean by that right away - others will use this rubric too.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit boring, good 'ol fashioned **understandable** could work.